# Retrieve the value from a 3D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Let say I have a 3D array like this

```
[
  [
    [3.12234, 50.12322],
    [3.12332, 12.12323],
    [3.431232, 122.22317],
  ],
]
```

How should i code to get any one of the value in this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You can use array `indexing` as:

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [3.12234, 50.12322],
    [3.12332, 12.12323],
    [3.431232, 122.22317],
  ],
];

const valueUsingMethod1 = arr[0][0];
console.log(valueUsingMethod1);
```

**2)** You can also use [`array-destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [3.12234, 50.12322],
    [3.12332, 12.12323],
    [3.431232, 122.22317],
  ],
];

const [[valueUsingMethod2]] = arr;
console.log(valueUsingMethod2);
```

**3)** You can also use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) here

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [3.12234, 50.12322],
    [3.12332, 12.12323],
    [3.431232, 122.22317],
  ],
];

const [firstValue] = arr.flat(1);
console.log(firstValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var test = [
  [
    [3.12234, 50.12322],
    [3.12332, 12.12323],
    [3.431232, 122.22317],
  ],
]

var open = test[0] // get the array
[2] // get either [3.12234, 50.12322], [3.12332, 12.12323], or [3.431232, 122.22317] 
[1] // get item [0] or [1] from each value
console.log(open);
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```